# How to create 2 level left navigation with code

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, object-model, spnavigationnode

I need to create a function which will build 2 level left navigation programmatically.
Function should take name/title and url.

Can some body show me how to create using SPNavigation or any other SP class.
Thanks.

Left Nav should be like:
TermCountry -> Country1(Input to my function with url),
               Country2(Input to my function with url)

Comment: You want to customize Left Navigation right ?

Comment: Yes.after site creation I need to change the existing left nav (which gets craeted by default) with code say feature receiver.

Comment: You want the left navigation to work with Terms? Or you want to set the left navigation just once?

Comment: It should be like on feature activation.No Terms.

Answer (score 0):

Navoneel,

I hope this should help:
[Programmatically Add and Remove Items from the Quick Launch Bar](http://geekswithblogs.net/MOSSLover/archive/2008/02/27/programmatically-add-and-remove-items-from-the-quick-launch-bar.aspx)

If you want to change the look and feel of the Quick Launch than you can apply CSS as shown in these: 
[Branding the Quick Launch in SharePoint 2010 – Part I](http://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/branding-the-quick-launch-in-sharepoint-2010-part-i/)
[Brand SharePoint: Quicklaunch - Getting ready to expose CSS (Part 1)](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Brand-SharePoint-Quicklaunch-Getting-ready-to-expose-CSS-Part-1.aspx)